# How to convert currency at a specific day's exchange rate?

Tags: worksheet-function, google-sheets

I need to convert 1 USD = INR on specified date (23/07/2017)

Using

```
=D5*GoogleFinance("CURRENCY:USDINR", "price", "23/07/2017")
```

But it is throwing an error, where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
=D5*index(GoogleFinance("CURRENCY:USDINR","price","23/07/2017"),2,2)
```

The error message seems clear enough to me: `Function MULTIPLY parameter 2 expects number values. But 'Date' is a text and cannot be coerced to a number.` Why 'Date'? ... because, as mentioned for [GOOGLEFINANCE](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093281):

> Historical data, even for a single day, will be returned as an expanded array with column headers.

[Try your formula without `D5*`.]

[INDEX](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098242) can be used to select a specific element from an array.